# NetLogo 5.3.1, error message "Expected ["

Tags: error-handling, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm learning ABM from a book called Agent-Based and Individual-Based Modeling by Railsback and Grimm. According to the book, the first complete model they walk through looks like this:

```
 globals
turtles-own
[
  time-since-last-found
]
  num-clusters
]
[
  time-since-last-found
]

[
  num-clusters
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set num-clusters 4
  ask n-of 4 patches
  [
    ask n-of 20 patches in-radius 5
    [
    set pcolor red
    ]
  ]
  create-turtles 2
  [
    set size 2
    set color yellow
    set time-since-last-found 999
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [search]
  to search
    if-else time-since-last-found <= 20
    [right (random 181) -90]
    [right (random 21) -10]

    forward 1
    ifelse pcolor = red
    [
      set time-since-last-found 0
      set pcolor yellow
    ]
    [
      set time-since-last-found time-since-last-found + 1
    ]
  end
```

The book says I should be able to to run the simple Mushroom Hunt model. But, instead, I keep getting an error message that says I need an extra [, "Expected [".

I have no idea where I need to put it. What's more, it really does seem to me that I don't need it and I don't understand why it's saying I do.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably make that comment an answer, Luck.

Comment: Done, thanks Nicolas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be helpful to check out the [Netlogo Programming Guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html) as you read through Railsback and Grimm. It helps outline proper syntax and explains in a different way what code needs to go in what place.

With your code above, there are several problems- for example, review `Globals` and `Turtles-own`. Note how square brackets should contain the variables in each of those blocks. Next, look at how procedures all start with `to` and finish with `end` - you should see that there is a "search" procedure nested in your "go" procedure above.